# handling asynchronus test with jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nestjs

```
it('throws an error if user signs up with email that is in use', async (done) => {
    fakeUserService.find = () =>
      Promise.resolve([{ id: 1, email: 'a', password: 'abc' } as User]);

    service.signup('anas123@gmail.com', 'anas1234').then(() => {
      done();
    });
```

error : rgument of type '(done: DoneCallback) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ProvidesCallback | undefined'.
Type '(done: DoneCallback) => Promise' is not assignable to type '(cb: DoneCallback) => void | undefined'.
Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'void'.ts(2345)

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose one: use `async` or use `done`:

### async

```
it('throws an error if user signs up with email that is in use', async () => {
    fakeUserService.find = () =>
      Promise.resolve([{ id: 1, email: 'a', password: 'abc' } as User]);

    await service.signup('anas123@gmail.com', 'anas1234')
})
```

### done

```
it('throws an error if user signs up with email that is in use', (done) => {
    fakeUserService.find = () =>
      Promise.resolve([{ id: 1, email: 'a', password: 'abc' } as User]);

    service.signup('anas123@gmail.com', 'anas1234').then(() => {
      done();
    });
})
```